# Redirection after login in React Native using Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Hi i am trying to navigate to dashboard screen after successfull login by setting token to asyncStorage, I am able to set token in asyncStorage but not able to navigate to dashboard after successfull login anything i need to modify in my code

**App.JS:**

```
const ApplicationNavigator = () => {
  const { Layout, darkMode, NavigationTheme } = useTheme()
  const { colors } = NavigationTheme
console.log("app.js")
let token;
AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
.then((value) => {
   token = JSON.parse(value);
  console.log('token is ', token);
});

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={[Layout.fill, { backgroundColor: colors.card }]}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={NavigationTheme} ref={navigationRef}>
        {!token && <AuthStack/>}
       {token && <MainStack/>}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default ApplicationNavigator
```

**My AuthStack:**
const AuthStack = () => {

```
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="LoginScreen"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**MainStack:**

```
<Tab.Navigator >
      <Tab.Screen name='Dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
      <Tab.Screen name='My Tasks' component={MyTaskStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name='Job Openings' component={JobOpeningsStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name='Candidates' component={CandidateStack} />

    </Tab.Navigator>
```

**And Login:**

```
const signIn = () => {
   let body={
    email:email,
    Password:password
   }
   console.log(body)
    fetch("http://testApplication/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson)
      
       AsyncStorage.setItem("token", responseJson.token)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('data stored..');
      });
       let token =  AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
       console.log(token)
       
        navigation.navigate("Dashboard")
        
      });
  };
```

I am able to login and getting the below error:
**The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {} was not handled by any navigator.
You need to pass the name of the screen to navigate to.**

I tried to change the navigation.navigate("Dashboard")  to -->navigation.navigate({ key: Dashboard });
for that also i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't manually navigate when conditionally rendering screens, instead listen to changes in `token` and navigation will automatically happen to the correct screen.

E.g. wrap `AsyncStorage` to listen to changes, see [Adding event listener functionality](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/401) for more info.

See [Authentication flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) for details on how to implement such flows.

Comment: I am new to react native, Can you please let me know  in my code where i need to change